# Debain(buster) su not working properly, command not found

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, root, su

- For example: I installed ifconfig
- First i become root with "su"
- Now I write "ifconfig" and get: "command not found".
- I write "sudo ifconfig" and now it works.

This seems to happen with a lot of programs (not all).

Another example: apt-get does not seem to properly install applications if I'm not using the same method.

I should not need to write sudo if I'm already root.

Why is that? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL,DR: Use `su --login` or `sudo`.

---

Debian sets a different `PATH` for regular users. In `/etc/profile`, you can see that the defaults reserve `/sbin` for root:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH
```

`type ifconfig` says the utility resides at `/sbin/ifconfig` which is why regular users can't access it easily. When you run `su` with no arguments, the calling user's environment is preserved, including the `PATH` variable. `sudo`, on the other hand, provides a fresh environment and overrides the calling user's `PATH`.

---

The reason why you believe `su` is malfunctioning is because resetting `PATH` and `IFS` by default is legacy behavior. buster recently switched to the `util-linux` implementation of `su` which works differently; see `/usr/share/doc/util-linux/NEWS.Debian.gz` for details.

Comment: Or simply `/sbin/ifconfig` without `sudo` nor `su`

Answer (score 0):

As dsstorefile1 said, the behaviour was changed.

Either you run "su -" instead of "su" or you could

add "ALWAYS_SET_PATH yes" to "/etc/login.defs" to preserve old Debians behavior.

Answer (score 0):

use `su - root` instead of `su root`. Then type `adduser username sudo`

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you [edit] your answer and explain *why* OP should do this?